# Uploading artifacts from multiple configurations to maven in gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I cannot seem to be able to publish a second set of jars to a local maven repo using a separate upload task, different to `uploadArchives`. Here's my setup:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: project.releaseRepoUrl)
      snapshotRepository(url: project.snapshotRepoUrl)
    }
  }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar){ ... }

artifacts{
  archives sourcesJar
}
```

The above works as expected. Then I have an additional `configuration`

```groovy
configurations{
  guiceArchives
}

task guiceJar(type: Jar){ ... }

task guiceSourcesJar(type: Jar){ ... }

artifacts{
  guiceArchives guiceJar
  guiceArchives guiceSourcesJar
  //archives guiceJar
  //archives guiceSourcesJar
}
```

Executing `gradle uploadArchives` works OK, but `gradle uploadGuiceArchives` does nothing:

```
:core:guiceClasses UP-TO-DATE
:core:guiceJar UP-TO-DATE
:core:guiceSourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:core:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:core:uploadArchives

BUILD FINISHED
```

Individual `guiceJar` and `guiceSourcesJar` tasks work fine by themselves, and printing out the contents of `guiceArchives` configuration also reveals that jars are correctly included as artifacts.

I tried temporarily assigning `guiceJar` and `guiceSourcesJar` to the `archives` configuration, which makes it complain saying:

```
A POM cannot have multiple artifacts with the same type and classifier.
```

Which is exactly what the [manual says](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub%3amultiple_artifacts_per_project). So I assumed that it is this artifact clash that was the cause of the problem.

So I fixed it using `addFilter` as the manual suggests, which worked great but only when `guiceJar` and `guiceSourcesJar` are assigned to `archives`. When I assign them back to `guiceArchives` and try `gradle uploadGuiceArchives` it still does nothing.

Is there no way to upload multiple artifacts with different upload tasks?

**Solution:**

Here's the update with the solution provided by @Peter Niederwieser.

Just add this:

```groovy
uploadGuiceArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: project.releaseRepoUrl)
      snapshotRepository(url: project.snapshotRepoUrl)
    }
  }
}
```

*Note:* the `addFilter` is not needed.

Thanks!

**Edit2:**

For completeness, the `project.releaseRepoUrl` and `project.snapshotRepoUrl` are set to a local maven repository as follows:

```groovy
project.ext{
  releaseRepoUrl = "file://${project(':').projectDir}/../mvn-repo/releases"
  snapshotRepoUrl = "file://${project(':').projectDir}/../mvn-repo/snapshots"
}
```

Comment: Is this still the correct way to support configuration artifacts in the same project?

Comment: Haven't found any major feature updates in this area, so I guess it is still a valid, and the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you didn't define repositories for `uploadGuiceArchives` like you did for `uploadArchives`?

Comment: That was it, thanks! I completely failed to see the fact that repository configuration is per-task.